# Kivy button embedded in code doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I follow the tutorial but button appears only if i use .kv file.If I want to add it directly in python code,it doesn't appear.

```
class StackLayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def _init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        b = Button(text='Z')
        self.add_widget(b)
TheLabApp().run()
```

`

I tried to google it but still it works only with .kv file

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.